# Proving the tangent addition identity (by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\cos \theta \cos \phi$ to simplify in terms of $\tan$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In the tangent addition identity,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\tan(\theta + \phi) &=& \frac{\sin(\theta + \phi)}{\cos(\theta + \phi)} \\\\
&=& \frac{\sin\theta\cos\phi + \cos\theta\sin\phi}{\cos\theta\cos\phi - \sin\theta\sin\phi} \\\\
&=& \frac{\left(\frac{\sin\theta\cos\phi + \cos\theta\sin\phi}{\cos\theta\cos\phi}\right)}{\left(\frac{\cos\theta\cos\phi - \sin\theta\sin\phi}{\cos\theta\cos\phi}\right)} \\\\
&=& \frac{\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} + \frac{\sin\phi}{\cos\phi}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{\sin\theta\sin\phi}{\cos\theta\cos\phi}\right)} \\\\
&=& \frac{\tan\theta+\tan\phi}{1-\tan\theta\tan\phi} \\\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
I understand how this works, but I'm trying to understand why we multiply numerator and denominator in the third line by $\frac{1}{\cos\theta\cos\phi}$ . I get that this allows us to simplify the solution in terms of $\tan, \theta,$ and $\phi$ (or whatever variable is used for the proof), but is that the only reason we further simplify it beyond that step?

Comment: I mean, why not?

Comment: In a word, yes, the reason is to express $\tan(A+B)$ in terms of $\tan A$ and $\tan B.$ It’s nicer that way. To express it in terms of the bad old days, you only have to use one lookup table. (Before computers and calculators, we had tables of logarithms  and trig functions. We could have a table for values of $\tan A$ for $A=1^\circ,2^\circ,\dots,360^\circ$ and then tables for smaller $B$ for values $B=0.01,0.02,\dots,0.99$ and compute a value for $\tan(A+B)$ if you needed that fineness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because it is nicer.

For a more practical reason…

In the bad old days before computers, trig functions and logarithms were computed, by people who needed them, using lookup tables. Books were published with pre-calculated tables of the values of these functions.

For tangent, you can keep a table for $\theta=0^o,1^o,\dots,89^o$ and a table for $\theta=0.01,\dots,0.99$ then use this formula for $\tan(A+B)$ to get finer angles by picking $A$ from the first table and $B$ from the second.

The other functions would require four tables to compute, say $\sin(A+B).$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense for past uses; I also hadn't considered there are 4 unknowns prior to simplifying it to 2 unknowns. Thanks for the alternative insight!